# Как добавить дополнительные lib файлы в пакете conan.io

Tags: c++, conan

Помогите пожалуйста. Сейчас создаю сonan.io рецепт для библиотеки proj (https://proj.org/) нужно ее скомпилировать под Visual Studion. Не смог ее найти не в одном из репозитариев. Смог все скомпилировать и добавить нужные библиотеки. Но вот при линковки возникли проблемы. Нужно добавить следующие lib файлы: ws2_32, zlib,libcrypto,crypt32,libssl. 
На сколько я понял из документации при выполнении команды conan install  должен вызываться метод package_info где и прописываются данные дополнительные библиотеки. Но мне не удалось добиться вызова этого метода. 
Просьба:  Помогите пожалуйста добавить эти lib файлы при линковке. Где их нужно прописать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть рецепт который сейчас находится в стадии принятия в conan center:

https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/pull/1272/files

рекомендую попробовать его

чтобы добавить библиотеки (lib файлы), нужно добавить подобный код:

```
def package_id(self):
    if self.settings.os == "Windows":
        self.cpp_info.system_libs.extend(["ws2_32", "crypt32"])
```

чтобы добавить зависимости от zlib/OpenSSL, достаточно:

```
def requirements(self):
    self.requires.add("openssl/1.1.1d")
    self.requires.add("zlib/1.2.11")
```